# bison always gives syntax error

Tags: compiler-errors, bison

*UPDATE*
Adding 'INT' and 'STRING' types to primary_expression solves many (not all) of the errors, despite it not being part of the ANSI C yacc grammar. Oh well, i'll have to make due for now.

I'm working on a writing a compiler and for the life of me, I cannot pinpoint why this grammar is giving me a syntax error. Anyone that can spot what's going on here would be greatly appreciated. Here is the grammar

```
%locations
%defines
%token-table
%union {
    int value;
    char symbol;
    char *str;
};
%{
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    int yylex();
    int yyparse(void);
    void yyerror(const char *str);
    void lyyerror(YYLTYPE t, char *str, ...);

    extern FILE *yyin;


%}


%start program
%type <value> type
%type <value> compound_instruction
%type <value> instruction
%type <value> expression_instruction
%type <value> iteration_instruction
%type <value> select_instruction
%type <value> jump_instruction
%type <value> expression
%type <value> assignment
%type <value> instruction_list
%type <value> cond_instruction
%type <value> condition
%type <value> expression_additive
%type <value> expression_multiplicative
%type <value> unary_expression
%type <value> expression_postfixee
%type <value> primary_expression



%token INT
%token STRING
%token CONST_INT
%token CONST_STRING

%token IDENT

%token EXTERN

%token IF
%token ELSE
%token WHILE
%token DO
%token RETURN
%token FOR
%token THEN

%token ASSIGNMENT
%token LESSTHAN
%token EQUAL
%token GREATERTHAN
%token LESSTHANEQUAL
%token GREATERTHANEQUAL
%token DIFF

%left PLUS
%left MINUS
%left MULTI
%left DIV

%left SHIFTRIGHT
%left SHIFTLEFT
%left MODULO

%%
program :
external-declaration
| program external-declaration
;

external-declaration :
declaration          // Declaration Global
| EXTERN declaration // Set Extern attribute
| function-definition
;

function-definition :
type function_declarator decl_glb_fct compound_instruction
// generate code function
;

decl_glb_fct :
// Get function name - Create a spot to store the function - set attributes
;

declaration :
type declarator_list ';'
;

type :
INT                     // set INT
| STRING                // set String
;

declarator_list :
declarator              // Propagate code
| declarator_list ',' declarator
;

declaration_list :
declaration                 // Set locals
| declaration_list declaration      // Set locals
;

declarator :
IDENT                   // Create Variable
| function_declarator               // Create Function
;

function_declarator :
IDENT '(' ')'               // Create function name
| IDENT '(' parameter_list ')'      // Create partial function
;

parameter_list :
parameter_declaration
| parameter_list ',' parameter_declaration // Insert parameters
;

parameter_declaration :
type IDENT              // Type declaration
;

instruction :
';'
| compound_instruction {$$=$1;}
| expression_instruction  {$$=$1;}
| iteration_instruction  {$$=$1;}
| select_instruction  {$$=$1;}
| jump_instruction {$$=$1;}
;

expression_instruction :
expression ';'
| assignment ';'
;

assignment :
IDENT ASSIGNMENT expression
;

compound_instruction :
block_start declaration_list instruction_list block_end {$$=$3;}
| block_start declaration_list block_end
| block_start instruction_list block_end {$$=$2;}
| block_start block_end
;


block_start :
'{'  // Init your hash table - symbol table
;

block_end :
'}' // Empty hash table
;

instruction_list :
instruction  {$$=$1;}
| instruction_list instruction {$$=$2;}
;

select_instruction :
cond_instruction instruction
| cond_instruction instruction ELSE instruction
;

cond_instruction :
IF '(' condition ')' {$$=$3;}
;

iteration_instruction :
WHILE '(' condition ')' instruction // Handle while loop
| DO instruction WHILE '(' condition ')'
| FOR '(' assignment ';' condition ';' assignment ')' instruction
;

jump_instruction:
RETURN expression ';'
;

condition :
expression comparison_operator expression
;

comparison_operator :
EQUAL
| DIFF
| LESSTHAN
| GREATERTHAN
| LESSTHANEQUAL
| GREATERTHANEQUAL
;

expression :
expression_additive {$$=$1;}
| expression SHIFTLEFT expression_additive //  Compute expression
| expression SHIFTRIGHT expression_additive // Compute expression
;

expression_additive :
expression_multiplicative {$$=$1;}
| expression_additive PLUS expression_multiplicative // Compute expression
| expression_additive MINUS expression_multiplicative // Compute expression
;

expression_multiplicative :
unary_expression{$$=$1;}
| expression_multiplicative MULTI unary_expression
| expression_multiplicative DIV unary_expression
| expression_multiplicative MODULO unary_expression
;

unary_expression:
expression_postfixee {$$=$1;}
| MINUS unary_expression
;

expression_postfixee :
primary_expression {$$=$1;}
| IDENT '(' argument_expression_list')'
| IDENT '(' ')'
;

argument_expression_list:
expression
| argument_expression_list',' expression
;

primary_expression :
IDENT
| CONST_INT
| CONST_STRING
| '(' expression ')'
;
%%
```

Here is the lex file.

```
%option noyywrap
%option stack
%option yylineno
%s COMMENT
%s MACRO
%s ENDOFLINE
%s DEFINE
%s STRING
%{
    #include "calc2.tab.hpp"

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    //#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
    //#define YYSTYPE int
    //extern YYSTYPE yylval;

    #define YY_USER_ACTION

    extern YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_string(const char *str);

    yy_buffer_state* main_buffer = 0;
    yy_buffer_state* expansion_buffer = 0;

    std::string var,bar,biz;
%}
%%
[ \t\n]+
^"#include ".*\n                {
    // can put code to "store" include files here, or else switch to a 'FILE' state
    //BEGIN DEFINE;
}
"if"                            { ECHO; /*printf("        IF\n")                      */; return IF;}
"else"                          { ECHO; /*printf("        ELSE\n")                    */; return ELSE;}
"while"                         { ECHO; /*printf("        WHILE\n")                   */; return WHILE;}
"do"                            { ECHO; /*printf("        DO\n")                      */; return DO;}
"return"                        { ECHO; /*printf("        RETURN\n")                  */; return RETURN;}
"for"                           { ECHO; /*printf("        FOR\n")                     */; return FOR;}
"then"                          { ECHO; /*printf("        THEN\n")                    */; return THEN;}
"="                             { ECHO; /*printf("        ASSIGNMENT\n")              */; return ASSIGNMENT;}
"+"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        PLUS_OP\n")                 */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return PLUS;}
"("                             { ECHO; /*printf("        L_PARENTHESIS\n")           */; return LEFTPARENS ;}
")"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        R_PARENTHESIS\n")           */; return RIGHTPARENS ;}
"-"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        MINUS_OP\n")                */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return MINUS;}
"*"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        MULT_OP\n")                 */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return MULTI;}
"/"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        DIV_OP\n")                  */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return DIV;}
"%"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        MODULO_OP\n")               */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return MODULO;}
"<<"                            { ECHO; /*printf("        LEFT_SHIFT\n")              */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return SHIFTLEFT;}
">>"                            { ECHO; /*printf("        RIGHT_SHIFT\n")             */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return SHIFTRIGHT;}
"=="                            { ECHO; /*printf("        COMPARISON_OP\n")           */;                                               }
"!="                            { ECHO; /*printf("        NOT_EQUAL\n")               */; yylval.value = atoi(yytext); return DIFF;}
"<"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        LESS_THAN\n")               */; yylval.value = atoi(yytext); return INF;}
">"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        GREATER_THAN\n")            */; yylval.value = atoi(yytext); return SUP;}
"<="                            { ECHO; /*printf("        LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL\n")      */; yylval.value = atoi(yytext); return INFEQUAL;}
">="                            { ECHO; /*printf("        GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL\n")   */; yylval.value = atoi(yytext); return SUPEQUAL;}
"int"                           { ECHO; /*printf("        INT DECLARATION\n")         */; return INT;}
"string"                        { ECHO; /*printf("        STRING DECLARATION\n")      */; return STRING;}
"extern"                        { ECHO; /*printf("        EXTERN\n")                  */; return EXTERN;}
";"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        SEMICOLON\n")               */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return ';';}
"{"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        LEFT_BRACE\n")              */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return '{';}
"}"                             { ECHO; /*printf("        RIGHT_BRACE\n")             */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return '}';}
","                             { ECHO; /*printf("        COMMA\n")                   */; yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return ',';}
[0-9]+                          { ECHO; /*printf("        INTEGER\n")                 */; yylval.value = atoi(yytext); return INT;}
"\""[^"\""\n]*"\""              { ECHO; /*printf("        STRING_LITERAL\n")          */; yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return STRING;}
"\""[^"\""\n]*$                 { ECHO; /*printf("        * Unterminated String *\n") */;                                             }
"const int"                     { ECHO; /*printf("        CONST INT DECLARATION\n")   */; return CONST_INT;}
"const string"                  { ECHO; /*printf("        CONST STRING DECLARATION\n")*/; return CONST_STRING;}
"/*"                            { BEGIN COMMENT                                     ;}
<COMMENT>"*/"                   { BEGIN INITIAL                                     ;}
<COMMENT>([^*]|\n)+|.
<COMMENT><<EOF>>                {

    //ECHO;
    /*printf("* Unterminated Comment *\n")*/;
    yyterminate();

}
<DEFINE>"#define " { // probably redundant but not wanting to break code right now

    BEGIN MACRO;

}
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* { // looks for IDENTIFIERS not sharing name with macro NAME

    //if(strncmp(yytext, var.c_str(),strlen(yytext))==0) {

        // ** this is sort of a hack, because without grammar, hard to resolve naming collisions... **
        // ** except it helps that I can rely on UPPERCASE macro naming convention
      //  main_buffer = YY_CURRENT_BUFFER;
       // expansion_buffer = yy_scan_string(biz.c_str()); // lex macro expansion and send to stdout
       // yy_switch_to_buffer(expansion_buffer);

   // }
    // this will create one superfluous IDENTIFIER, not sure how to rid of it, yet
    // also, it's late and I'm tired of guessing what i've missed that wasn't in the actual project descript
   // else ECHO; /*printf("        IDENTIFIER\n")*/ return IDENT;
   ECHO;
   //yylval.str = strdup(yytext);
   return IDENT;

}
<MACRO>[A-Z]+" " { // find macro NAME

    var = yytext; BEGIN ENDOFLINE;

}
<ENDOFLINE>.*\n { // store the rest in string variable

    biz = yytext; BEGIN INITIAL;

}
<<EOF>> {

    if (expansion_buffer)
    {
        // We were doing an expansion, return to where
        // we were.
        yy_switch_to_buffer(main_buffer);
        yy_delete_buffer(expansion_buffer);
        expansion_buffer = 0;
    }
    else
    yyterminate();
}
%%
```

Sample output using just the lex file.

```
   extern int bar( int baz );

int foo(int count)
{

    int sum;

    for (int 1 = 1; i <= count; i++)
        sum = sum + foo2(i);

    return sum;

}

int main(void) {


    string "car";
    printf("%d", IF);
    const string("Hello, World!");
    /* comments */
    if(1)
        return 1;
    return 0;


}

externToken: 263 (extern)
intToken: 258 (int)
barToken: 262 (bar)
(Token: 282 (()
intToken: 258 (int)
bazToken: 262 (baz)
)Token: 283 ())
;Token: 59 (;)
intToken: 258 (int)
fooToken: 262 (foo)
(Token: 282 (()
intToken: 258 (int)
countToken: 262 (count)
)Token: 283 ())
{Token: 123 ({)
intToken: 258 (int)
sumToken: 262 (sum)
;Token: 59 (;)
forToken: 269 (for)
(Token: 282 (()
intToken: 258 (int)
1Token: 258 (1)
=Token: 271 (=)
1Token: 258 (1)
;Token: 59 (;)
iToken: 262 (i)
<=Token: 275 (<=)
countToken: 262 (count)
;Token: 59 (;)
iToken: 262 (i)
+Token: 278 (+)
+Token: 278 (+)
)Token: 283 ())
sumToken: 262 (sum)
=Token: 271 (=)
sumToken: 262 (sum)
+Token: 278 (+)
foo2Token: 262 (foo2)
(Token: 282 (()
iToken: 262 (i)
)Token: 283 ())
;Token: 59 (;)
returnToken: 268 (return)
sumToken: 262 (sum)
;Token: 59 (;)
}Token: 125 (})
intToken: 258 (int)
mainToken: 262 (main)
(Token: 282 (()
voidToken: 262 (void)
)Token: 283 ())
{Token: 123 ({)
stringToken: 5 (string)
"car"Token: 5 ("car")
;Token: 59 (;)
printfToken: 262 (printf)
(Token: 282 (()
"%d"Token: 5 ("%d")
,Token: 44 (,)
IFToken: 262 (IF)
)Token: 283 ())
;Token: 59 (;)
const stringToken: 261 (const string)
(Token: 282 (()
"Hello, World!"Token: 5 ("Hello, World!")
)Token: 283 ())
;Token: 59 (;)
ifToken: 264 (if)
(Token: 282 (()
1Token: 258 (1)
)Token: 283 ())
returnToken: 268 (return)
1Token: 258 (1)
;Token: 59 (;)
returnToken: 268 (return)
0Token: 258 (0)
;Token: 59 (;)
}Token: 125 (})
```

Sample output from above program to be parsed.

```
extern declare EXTERN
int INT type
bar(int INT type
baz PARAMETER
);int INT type
foo(int INT type
count PARAMETER
){int INT type
sum;for(intParse Error: 
syntax error, unexpected INT, expecting IDENT
```

Interestingly, if I add semantic action to function-definition like so:

```
function-definition : {printf("print something");}
type function_declarator decl_glb_fct compound_instruction
```

Then I get a different parser error:

```
extern declare EXTERN
int INT type
bar(int INT type
baz declare PARAMETER
);int INT type
foo(int INT type
count declare PARAMETER
){Parse Error: 
*** syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ';' or ',' ***
```

This is a behavior which I do not understand.

Comment: Can you give examples of non-empty files that don't parse, along with the parse errors that you get after setting `%define parse.error verbose`?

Comment: Ok. Yes.  extern int foo(int x) will throw syntax error just before Left parens.

Comment: "syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting INT or STRING"

Comment: Wow did not know that was even an option. I spent most of the day trying to implement the detailed error reporting outlined in the O'reilly media Flex/Bison book. Couldn't get that, either.

Comment: If I change the start rule to program : error, it will say "unexpected EXTERN"

Comment: The empty file does not parse because `program` requires at least one external declaration. That is, the empty file is simply not a valid program. I'm not sure why the function definition does not parse. If the parse error really points at the opening parenthesis and calls it an identifier, your lexer may be confused.

Comment: @sepp2k hey, I posted the lex file. Could you maybe take a look when you get a chance? Thanks.

Comment: Yiou don't have any lex actions for whitespace, newline, etc. For example the whitespace rule should be something like `[ \t\r\n\f]+ ;`

Comment: @EJP, that's the first rule I have, at the top.